# Populating Datagrid

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I am creating a pageant scoring system,

I have this functions for populating my datagridview's first column using query:

```vb
  Public Sub searchContestant()
    If comboCategory.SelectedIndex <> 0 Then
        Dim id As Integer = Login.JudgeBindingSource1.Current("Cont_id")
        Dim critID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text)
        'search the contest record by the contest_id
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim reader2 As SqlDataReader
        Dim dt = New DataTable()
        Dim nc As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BROWNIE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSS;Integrated Security=True"

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from Criteria where Cat_id = '" & critID & "' ", con)
            Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from Contestant where Cont_id = '" & id.ToString() & "' ", con)
            con.Open()

            ' Execute Query  
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            nc.Name = "Contestants"
            nc.Width = 250
            nc.ReadOnly = True
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(nc)

            While reader.Read()
                nc = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                nc.Name = "(" & reader.GetString(2) & "%)" & reader.GetString(1)
                nc.HeaderText = "(" & reader.GetString(2) & "%)" & reader.GetString(1)
                nc.Width = 150
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add(nc)
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close() 'Whether there is error or not. Close the connection.    '
        End Try

        Try

            'populate contestant rows
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BROWNIE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSS;Integrated Security=True"

            Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from Contestant where Cont_id = '" & id.ToString() & "' ", con)
            con.Open()
            reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()

            While reader2.Read()
                nc = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                nc.Width = 100
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader2.GetString(2).ToString())
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close() 'Whether there is error or not. Close the connection.    '
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

And for succeeding columns :

```vb
Public Sub searchCriteria()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim reader4 As SqlDataReader
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    Dim nc As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

    DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

    Try

        'populate Criteria
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BROWNIE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSS;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from Criteria where Cat_id = '" & lblID.Text & "' ", con)
        con.Open()

        reader4 = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader4.Read
            nc = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            nc.Name = reader4.GetString(1).ToString & Chr(13) & reader4.GetString(2).ToString & "%"

            nc.Width = 100
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(nc)
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close() 'Whether there is error or not. Close the connection.    '
    End Try

End Sub
```

This is the output:

[image]

And everytime a judge login, I insert data into the system with this function:

```vb
Public Sub makeTransaction()
    Dim con2 As New SqlConnection

    'get the judge id upon logging in
    Dim judgeID = Login.JudgeBindingSource1.Current("Judge_id")

    'get the contest id of the judge
    Me.JudgeTableAdapter.FillByJudgeID(Me.PSSDataSet.Judge, judgeID)
    Dim JudgeContestid = Login.JudgeBindingSource1.Current("Cont_id")
    Me.ContestantTableAdapter.FillByContestID(Me.PSSDataSet.Contestant, JudgeContestid)

    'get the contestant id
    Me.ContestTableAdapter.FillByContestID(Me.PSSDataSet.Contest, JudgeContestid)
    Dim contestID As Integer = ContestBindingSource.Current("Cont_id")

    'get the category of the contest

    Me.CategoryTableAdapter.FillByContestID(Me.PSSDataSet.Category, Convert.ToInt32(contestID))
    For Each Category As DataRow In Me.PSSDataSet.Category.Rows
        Me.CriteriaTableAdapter.FillByCategoryID(Me.PSSDataSet.Criteria, Category("Cat_id"))
        For Each Contestant As DataRow In Me.PSSDataSet.Contestant.Rows
            For Each Criteria As DataRow In Me.PSSDataSet.Criteria.Rows
                TransactionsTableAdapter.Insert(JudgeContestid, Contestant("Con_id"), Criteria("Cri_id"), 0)
            Next
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```

Now my problem is, how can I populate the datagrid using the data recently made by `MakeTransaction()` function?

Comment: are you asking how to filter the grid so that only the logged-in judge's values are shown?

Comment: exactly,there must be " 0 " value on the grids

Comment: build the query to filter the values by judge and contestant.  hopefully, you have the scores stored by judgeid as well as by contestant.  The datamodel (and SQL) is more important here than code.